# Django Rest-Framework JWT authentication not working except Chrome?

Tags: python, django, google-chrome, django-rest-framework, jwt

In my Application I am using `Django rest_framework_jwt` for token based authentication.

I am getting Success while login and my token also generated. But after login, Nothing happened except Chrome browser.

In Chrome browser alone its works fine. But in Firefox and IE it doesn't work.
i.e :- It simply stay on the login page itself after getting token also.

My default renderer class is, `rest_framework.renderers.JSONRenderer` .
Please give the solution for my problem..